# I am getting this error using Eclipse : An error has occurred. See error log for more details. org/eclipse/egit/core/AdapterUtils

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling, ide, message

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fElb7.png)

I tried re-installing Eclipse and the same message appears. I'm new to Java and don't know exactly what to do. I'm looking in forums and can't find a solution to this. Thank you in advance if you can answer the question.

[image: Error messages]

I think this is the log. I'm getting the same errors on repeat apparently:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    org/eclipse/egit/core/AdapterUtils
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.selection.SelectionUtils.getSelectionContents(SelectionUtils.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.selection.SelectionUtils.getRepository(SelectionUtils.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.selection.SelectionUtils.getRepository(SelectionUtils.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.selection.RepositorySourceProvider.selectionChanged(RepositorySourceProvider.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.SelectionService.notifyListeners(SelectionService.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.SelectionService.handleSelectionChanged(SelectionService.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.SelectionService.lambda$0(SelectionService.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator$1.run(SelectionAggregator.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator.notifyListeners(SelectionAggregator.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator$5.lambda$0(SelectionAggregator.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.RunAndTrack.runExternalCode(RunAndTrack.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator$5.changed(SelectionAggregator.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionServiceImpl.setSelection(SelectionServiceImpl.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.selectionChanged(CompatibilityPart.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$1.run(Viewer.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2143)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1181)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1210)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4274)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4072)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1432)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.egit.core (158).
    .. 52 more
```

Those are the lines I get when clicking on a specific error

Comment: When exactly does the error occur? Can you share the stack trace (check the error log view)? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Most likely your Eclipse installation or parts of it are not up to date. Please show the entire error message, not just the stack trace. Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error (do not open it, just select the row), hit Ctrl+C and paste everything (make sure it starts with `eclipse.buildId=` and that nothing has been cropped; if you anonymize something say so) into your question formatted as _Sample Code_ (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like `<`). If more errors have been logged recently, first delete the error log and reproduce your issue.